# Difference between FIFO vs LIFO vs Lastonly in oozie

Tags: oozie

Could you please explain briefly how oozie jobs prioritize the jobs based on LIFO,FIFO and LASTONLY settings.
Mainly need the difference between LIFO and LASTONLY with timing examples.

Comment: sounds like a homework assignment. You can find explanations on LIFO, FIFO and LastONLY on wikipedia. SO is meant for software questions with a code example

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.1.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html) part of the Oozie documentation describes the difference.

Relevant part:

> **FIFO** (oldest first) *default.
>
> **LIFO** (newest first).
>
> **LAST_ONLY**: While FIFO and LIFO simply specify the order in which READY
>   actions should be executed, LAST_ONLY can actually cause some actions
>   to be SKIPPED and is a little harder to understand. When LAST_ONLY is
>   set, an action that is WAITING or READY will be SKIPPED when the
>   current time is past the next action’s nominal time. For example,
>   suppose action 1 and 2 are both READY, the current time is 5:00pm, and
>   action 2’s nominal time is 5:10pm. In 10 minutes from now, at 5:10pm,
>   action 1 will become SKIPPED, assuming it doesn’t transition to
>   SUBMITTED (or a terminal state) before then. This sounds similar to
>   the timeout control, but there are some important differences:
>
> 1. The timeout time is configurable while the LAST_ONLY time is effectively the frequency.
> 2. Reaching the timeout causes an action to transition to TIMEDOUT, which will cause the Coordinator Job to become RUNNINGWITHERROR and
>      eventually DONEWITHERROR. With LAST_ONLY, an action becomes SKIPPED
>      and the Coordinator Job remains RUNNING and eventually DONE.
> 3. The timeout is looking satisfying the data dependency, while LAST_ONLY is looking at the action itself. This means that the timeout
>      can only cause a transition from WAITING, while LAST_ONLY can cause a
>      transition from WAITING or READY.
>
> LAST_ONLY is useful if you want a recurring job, but do not actually
>   care about the individual instances and just always want the latest
>   action. For example, if you have a coordinator running every 10
>   minutes and take Oozie down for 1 hour, when Oozie comes back, there
>   would normally be 6 actions WAITING or READY to run. However, with
>   LAST_ONLY, only the current one will go to SUBMITTED and then RUNNING;
>   the others will go to SKIPPED.
>
> **NONE**: Similar to LAST_ONLY except instead of looking at the next
>   action’s nominal time, it looks at
>   oozie.coord.execution.none.tolerance in oozie-site.xml (default is 1
>   minute). When NONE is set, an action that is WAITING or READY will be
>   SKIPPED when the current time is more than the configured number of
>   minutes (tolerance) past that action’s nominal time. For example,
>   suppose action 1 and 2 are both READY, the current time is 5:20pm, and
>   both actions’ nominal times are before 5:19pm. Both actions will
>   become SKIPPED, assuming they don’t transition to SUBMITTED (or a
>   terminal state) before then.